# Create Table with java eclispe

Tags: java, mysql, database, ms-access, derby

I am trying to complete a homework assignment that where we use java to create a database in derby, access, and MySQL. I'm trying to create a table, but it won't let me. I've looked over my query and nothing seems to be wrong, but it still gives me this error.

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "order" at line 1, column 14.

I even checked my code in the derby connection tab. It worked for the other tables I created so, I thought nothing was wrong with it.
[The create table code in the derby connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQwve.png)

I don't know what to do and I'm on limited time. I've also added the correct libraries, my teacher confirmed it. Its due Sunday. Please help.

[pic of my table I'm trying to create in the driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olBAi.png)

Answer (score 1):

@Kie you could change the table name from order to something else like CustOrder, because order is a key word in SQL. Also i don't think there's any need for concatenating the query.